# how to recall android fragment without run again JSON?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-fragments, android-volley

I want if fragemnt is recall, the fragment show view it first call not run json again. my code after i open fragment again the fragment is request json again. I am a beginner in java/android programming but I was trying to add different tutorials to create a customized application that does what I want, this could be something easy to most of the people here but am stuck

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest billionaireReq = new JsonArrayRequest(getURL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            url_maps.put(obj.getString("title") + " - " + obj.getString("releaseYear"), obj.getString("image"));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    for (String name : url_maps.keySet()) {
                        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(getActivity());
                        // initialize a SliderLayout
                        textSliderView
                                .description(name)
                                .image(url_maps.get(name))
                                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop)
                                .setOnSliderClickListener(HomeFragment.this);

                        //add your extra information
                        textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
                        textSliderView.getBundle().putString("extra", name);

                        mSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "network issue: please enable wifi/mobile data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(billionaireReq);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    mSlider = (SliderLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.slider_home);
    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), gridViewStrings, gridViewImages));
    mSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Stack);
    mSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Top);
    mSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
    mSlider.setDuration(4000);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onSaveInstanceState` method to save instance of your json. In your case, uou have store it in `String` variable or in object that implements `Parcelable` interface. List of valid data structures to save is here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("yourString", yourJsonInstance);
    outState.putString("yourParcelableObj", yourParcelableObj);
    //some other variables to save state
}
```

You have to ways to restore your data, you can do it by override `onRestoreInstanceState` method. Or you can do it in `onCreate` method by checking if `savedInstanceState` store your data:

this runs after `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore data here
    yourJsonString = savedInstanceState.getString("yourString");
}
```

or this you can put in your `onCreate` method:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // Restore data here
    yourJsonString = savedInstanceState.getString("yourString");
} else{
    //else get your json normally
}
```

Comment: oh yeah, thanks answer but not only json i save to savedInstanceStat. i want the fragment only show view at first time with resume. example when i open the fragment A first time slide is 1 2 3 4 5 and i open fragment B, when i back the fragment A slide continue to 6 7 8 9 not to 1 again.

Comment: Can you save some variable with slide was opened last? I so, you can save it in `savedInstanceState`, after comeback restore this variable and get next slide if variable exists in `savedInstanceState`.

Comment: no, please can you give me example code? im using myinnos imagesliderwithswipeslibrary.

Comment: If it is this library https://github.com/myinnos/ImageSliderWithSwipes/blob/master/imagesliderwithswipeslibrary/src/main/java/in/myinnos/imagesliderwithswipeslibrary/SliderLayout.java Then in your layout you have method `getCurrentPosition` to get position, get it and save it, and then restore it like I showed above and use method `setCurrentPosition` to set current position.

Comment: can you give me simple code for save getCurrentPosition and Restore setCurrentPosition ?

Answer (score 2):

"my code after i open fragment again the fragment is request json again"
What i got from your question is, you don't want to request json again if you already visited same fragment in the past. you can do do one thing, When you visit fragment first time save to json object into the Bundle in the saveStateInstance(Bundle bundle) override method and when you revisit fragment check and extract json from paramer bundle of onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) method. In this way you can maintain state of the fragment.

Comment: example my questions is i have 2 tabs with fragment, first fragmen when i open it was request json to listview after listview complete i open fragment B and then i open fragment A again it show full listview complete not run json request and show to listview again.

Comment: Do you want to refresh listview when return back to fragment A? If yes, write the refresh logic means fetching json and setting adapter to listview in onCreateView() instead of onCreate()

Comment: no, i just want listview. but my code alway request again.

Comment: Don't you see listview when visiting fragment A again ?

Comment: "listview is request again before show" What does this means, can you explain What is your doubt in more clear way?

Comment: yeah i just my fragment show again without request. it is just simple questions.

Comment: Are you using viewPager for tab?

Comment: no, what i want is just see view same at last view before i open other fragment.

Comment: Solution may be different for different approach, if you are using Viewpager for tab then write pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit) once in oncreate(). limit is the number of fragments you are loading. and if you are not using viewpager but the tabhost then switching tabs don't recreate fragment so you just have to request json in onCreate() then save it into the List save the list in the Bundle object in saveInstanceState() and when revisiting fragment get the bundle data back in onCreateView and setAdapter to listview.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422569/how-to-disable-recreation-of-the-first-fragment-in-fragmentpageradapter-on-tab-s

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Viewpager then just add

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit)
```

[Refer this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965611/in-fragment-tabhost-listview-loading-everytime-on-tab-click)